# Heading Tag within a Header Element

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I just finished reading the HTML5 Developer's Cookbook and have a question. I've read the specs, but now I can't find the reference to what I'm trying to figure out.

In the HTML5 Developer's Cookbook, one of the code examples; figure 1.9, listing 1.10 - is:

```
// ...
<header>
    <h1>Jase is awesome</h1>
</header>
// ...
```

Now, I understand when and where to use the `header` element, and I also understand when and where to use the `h1` tag. But, my question is, Should, or must we *always* or *only* use the `h1` tag inside a `header` element, as shown in the above example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a `<h1>` tag anywhere in the document where it's allowed. If it so happens that you're using it semantically in the `<header>` element, go right ahead. If your main title of the page is *not* within the `<header>` element, don't use it there.

In short, yes, if it fits. Use your best judgment.

Comment: See, I always associate the `header` tag (regardless of what the specs say (I can't remember what they say)) as being that thing you use at the top of the document, or somewhere in the document that describes in some way what the page is about. That's why I was confused about having all h1's inside a `header`, because there's plenty of scenarios where you wouldn't put a header, but would put a `h1`.

Comment: The `<header>` is generally at the top of the document. It usually just contains content that is synonymous across pages. (logo, navigation, ads sometimes) Depending on how you use it, putting your `<h1>` tag inside of it (for a logo, perhaps?) would be perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

No you can use it where ever you like